# PrimeNG dataTable not 'reload' table

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, primeng

I have `[value]="rows[indexString]"` for dataTable in template.
In component

```
rows: any = {}
newrow: any = {}
...
addNewRow(key: string) {

  let rows = {...this.rows}
  let newrow = {_key: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), title: this.newrow.title}
  
  if (rows[key]) {
    rows[key].push(newrow)
  } else {
    rows[key] = newrow
  }
  
  this.rows = rows

}
```

Basically I am following tutorial from [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/crud)

Only the first row rendered in table, in template `{{rows | json}}`, everything is there:

```
{
  "210386": [
    {
      "_key": 9173,
      "title": "Row one"
    },
    {
      "_key": 6201,
      "title": "Row Two"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `this.rows` is an `object`, not an `array`.

I think the problem might be the way you're copying `this.rows`. You are using spread operator to create a new object from `this.rows` copy. What you want is an array.

Try this instead:

```
let rows = [...this.rows]
```

EDIT:
I'll complete my answer.
The problem is reference to your object is lost when copying rows ans reassigning them. Then observation of changes can't occur.

What you need to copy is the array you are currently working with. Not the whole object.

```
  addNewRow(key: string) {

    let newrow = {_key: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), title: this.newrow.title}

    let rows = [];

    if (this.rows.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // check is key already exists
      rows = [...this.rows[key], newRow];
    } else {
      rows = [newRow]
    }

    this.rows[key] = rows;

  }
```

Comment: Just in right time, this work perfect. Am give up for p-dataTable and start 'normal' table, obviously am over-thinking, it's nice and simple solution